# Laplace transform to solve ODE with boundary condition not at $0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I want to solve $y''+y =\begin{cases} 
      t & t\leq 1 \\
      0 & t>1
   \end{cases}$
where $y(0)=0$ and $y'(\pi)=1$ using the Laplace transform.
I think I can write the piecewise function as $f(t)=t(u(t)-u(t-1))$ but I'm unsure about what to do with the boundaries, since

$\mathcal{L}\{y''\} = s^2\mathcal{L}\{y\}-sy(0)-y'(0)$ and
$\mathcal{L}\{y'\} = s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)$.

I thought about defining a new variable say $t=x+\pi$, such that when $t=\pi$, $x=0$ but when $t=0$, $x=-\pi$ which creates the same problem

Comment: The Laplace transform is not particularly well-suited to BVPs, but you can do it if you just leave $y'(0)$ as a parameter to be determined and then solve for it by using the other boundary condition at the end of the problem. The numerical method associated with this technique is called the shooting method (but here you can just do it analytically).

Comment: you mean $y'(\pi)$?

Comment: No, $y'(0)$ is what appears in the LT, you invert the LT leaving it as an unknown parameter, then set $y'(\pi)=1$ and try to solve for $y'(0)$.

Comment: I see what you mean - that makes sense, thank you